I am trying to make Xen based on cross compilation. However, it keeps showing some issues
The Version of Xen is 4.12.0
I am using Linux Mint XFCE
Following is the way the error is generated:
wget -c https://downloads.xenproject.org/release/xen/4.12.0/xen-4.12.0.tar.gz tar xf xen-4.12.0.tar.gz cd xen-4.12.0
make dist-xen XEN_TARGET_ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu-
mahmed@mahmed-System-Product-Name:~/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0$ make dist-xen XEN_TARGET_ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu-
make -C xen install
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen'
make -f Rules.mk _install
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen'
make -C tools
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/tools'
make symbols
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/tools'
make[4]: 'symbols' is up to date.
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/tools'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/tools'
make -f /home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/Rules.mk include/xen/compile.h
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen'
 Xen 4.12.0
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen'
[ -e include/asm ] || ln -sf asm-arm include/asm
[ -e arch/arm/efi ] && for f in boot.c runtime.c compat.c efi.h;\
    do test -r arch/arm/efi/$f || \
       ln -nsf ../../../common/efi/$f arch/arm/efi/; \
    done; \
    true
make -f /home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/Rules.mk -C include
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/include'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/include'
make -f /home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/Rules.mk -C arch/arm asm-offsets.s
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/arch/arm'
make[3]: 'asm-offsets.s' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/arch/arm'
make -f /home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/Rules.mk include/asm-arm/asm-offsets.h
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen'
make[3]: 'include/asm-arm/asm-offsets.h' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen'
make -f /home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/Rules.mk -C arch/arm /home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/xen
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/arch/arm'
make -f /home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/Rules.mk -C /home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/common built_in.o
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/common'
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -DBUILD_ID -fno-strict-aliasing -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unused-local-typedefs   -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -nostdinc -fno-builtin -fno-common -Werror -Wredundant-decls -Wno-pointer-arith -Wvla -pipe -D__XEN__ -include /home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/include/xen/config.h '-D__OBJECT_FILE__="trace.o"' -Wa,--strip-local-absolute -MMD -MF ./.trace.o.d -mcpu=generic -mgeneral-regs-only   -I/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/include -fno-stack-protector -fno-exceptions -Wnested-externs -DGCC_HAS_VISIBILITY_ATTRIBUTE -c trace.c -o trace.o
trace.c: In function ‘__trace_hypercall’:
trace.c:826:19: error: taking address of packed member of ‘struct <anonymous>’ may result in an unaligned pointer value [-Werror=address-of-packed-member]
  826 |     uint32_t *a = d.args;
      |                   ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[4]: *** [/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/Rules.mk:196: trace.o] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/common'
make[3]: *** [/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/Rules.mk:184: /home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/common/built_in.o] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/arch/arm'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:143: /home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/xen] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:45: install] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen'
make: *** [Makefile:123: install-xen] Error 2
mahmed@mahmed-System-Product-Name:~/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0$ 

If I run this command the error is different:
make dist-xen XEN_TARGET_ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu-     CFLAGS="-w"
mahmed@mahmed-System-Product-Name:~/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0$ make dist-xen XEN_TARGET_ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu-     CFLAGS="-w"
make -C xen install
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen'
make -f Rules.mk _install
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen'
make -C tools
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/tools'
make symbols
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/tools'
make[4]: 'symbols' is up to date.
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/tools'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/tools'
make -f /home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/Rules.mk include/xen/compile.h
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen'
 Xen 4.12.0
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen'
[ -e include/asm ] || ln -sf asm-arm include/asm
[ -e arch/arm/efi ] && for f in boot.c runtime.c compat.c efi.h;\
    do test -r arch/arm/efi/$f || \
       ln -nsf ../../../common/efi/$f arch/arm/efi/; \
    done; \
    true
make -f /home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/Rules.mk -C include
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/include'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/include'
make -f /home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/Rules.mk -C arch/arm asm-offsets.s
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/arch/arm'
make[3]: 'asm-offsets.s' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/arch/arm'
make -f /home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/Rules.mk include/asm-arm/asm-offsets.h
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen'
make[3]: 'include/asm-arm/asm-offsets.h' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen'
make -f /home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/Rules.mk -C arch/arm /home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/xen
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/arch/arm'
make -f /home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/Rules.mk -C /home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/common built_in.o
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/common'
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -w -c trace.c -o trace.o
trace.c:20:10: fatal error: asm/io.h: No such file or directory
   20 | #include <asm/io.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[4]: *** [/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/Rules.mk:196: trace.o] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/common'
make[3]: *** [/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/Rules.mk:184: /home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/common/built_in.o] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/arch/arm'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:143: /home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen/xen] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:45: install] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/mahmed/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0/xen'
make: *** [Makefile:123: install-xen] Error 2
mahmed@mahmed-System-Product-Name:~/Projects/xenonarm/xen-4.12.0$ 

I am following this guide: https://medium.com/@denisobrezkov/xen-on-arm-and-qemu-1654f24dea75
I tried many ways to resolve the issue but it still persists.
